# Creating a UserDefined CLR function in .Net

Tags: .net, class-library, sqlclr, sql-function

i want to create a CLR function, i created a normal class library file and coded as below, i dont want to use SqlServerProject, as i cannot find some classes there.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Types;

    namespace ClassLibrary1
    {
        public partial class Class1
        {
            [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
            public static SqlString GetPassword(SqlString Value)
            {
                return Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

i compiled the code and created assembly from sqlserver like this

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY ASSEM
authorization dbo
FROM 'E:\NBM Sites\tvt.stage.asentechdev1.com\ClassLibrary1.dll' WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE;
```

and created a function as below

```
CREATE FUNCTION SampleFunc
(   
    @value nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max) with execute as caller
AS
    External Name ASSEM.Class1.GetPassword
GO
```

but the above create function threw an error saying.

```
Could not find Type 'Class1' in assembly 'ClassLibrary1'.
```

i dont understand, why the class1 is not recognised, as also i have made it public.
Please any one help me for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the namespace that your class is in (ClassLibrary1).  So the correct create function statement is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SampleFunc
(   
  @value nvarchar(max)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max) with execute as caller
AS
  External Name [ASSEM].[ClassLibrary1.Class1].[GetPassword]
GO
```